# PHP Unexpected T_encapsed

Tags: php

I running a PHp script to present a table on the database, but i get the error
`Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in`

The line below is query line

```
echo "<td><img src='" .$row['ImageURL'] ."' style='width: 200px; height: 150px;' />."-".$row['Name'] ."</td>"";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an unnecessary and faulty concatenation after `/>` and an extra quote on the end:

```
echo "<td><img src='" .$row['ImageURL'] ."' style='width: 200px; height: 150px;' /> -".$row['Name'] ."</td>";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^--------------------^^^
//-----------------------------------------------------------Remove dot and quote---------------Remove quote
```

The whole thing is better done without concatenations in a double-quoted string.  Wrap the array elements in `{}`.

```
 echo "<td><img src='{$row['ImageURL']}' style='width: 200px; height: 150px;' /> - {$row['Name']} </td>";
```

However, you probably ought to be sure you have escaped these for HTML output with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$imgurl = htmlspecialchars($row['ImageURL'], ENT_QUOTES);
$name = htmlspecialchars($row['Name']);
echo "<td><img src='$imageurl' style='width: 200px; height: 150px;' /> - $name </td>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
echo "<td><img src='" .$row['ImageURL'] ."' style='width: 200px; height: 150px;' /> - ".$row['Name'] ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

this is why you don't echo html

Youre missing a `"` after the image element.

This is much more readable...

```
<td><img src="<?php echo $row['ImageURL'] ?>" style="..."><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `"` at the end    `."</td>"";`
It should be `."</td>";`